# Is it possible to have multiple SAML response url in one SAML SP metadata?

Tags: metadata, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am really new to SAML, but did read through tutorials (at least really tried). I am using samltest.id as IDP and my code will act like SP.

On my local machine, it works as far as I can see(samltest's user page shows and I get redirected back to the correct place). However, when deployed to our preprod site, the SAML process fails.
From the samltest's log, I can see this as my request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://prep-auth-project.xxxx.xxx/saml/acs"
    Destination="https://samltest.id/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO"
    ID="_b180d98092dd4ff78693d0f5687dc059"
    IssueInstant="2023-11-09T08:49:13Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer>http://localhost:44326/saml</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Then further down the log, I see this:

```
 Endpoint Resolver org.opensaml.saml.common.binding.impl.DefaultEndpointResolver: Neither candidate endpoint location 'https://localhost:44326/saml/acs' nor response location 'null' matched 'https://prep-auth-project.xxxx.xxx/saml/acs'
```

So basically the error seems to be that my metadata's id is localhost and doesn't match with our preprod url.
Is there a way to provide multiple response location (e.g. 1 for localhost, 1 for preprod and 1 for prod)?
Or we will have to create separate metadata for different running url?

Comment: Why would you need the `localhost:xyz` endpoint on a preprod site?

Comment: in azure AD, one can configure an app with multiple return urls, so one won;t need to create the same thing multiple times to test openID. Does saml support the same or it is different?

Comment: Yes, the service provider descriptor in the metadata should be able to contain multiple valid assertion consumer endpoints. As per the [specs](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf) 2.4.4.